# Designing a div on real time fetch data HTML, CSS, Php, JavaScript and MySql

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I'm having a problem of putting a design for a div in my real time fetch data. Can you please give me some ideas or tricks how can i embed html and css in this type of codes so i can put some responsive designs for my website.

Here's my code for **index.php**

```
<div id="getdata"></div>
```

```js
<div id="getdata"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function dis()
{
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET","select.php",false);
 xmlhttp.send(null);
 document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
dis();
setInterval(function(){
dis();
},2000);
</script>
```

and here's my php and mysql for database connection **select.php** filename

```html
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password");
mysqli_select_db($link,"autorefresh");
$res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from table1");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
 echo $row["name"]." ".$row["city"];
 echo "<br>";

}


?>
```

-->

I am looking the best way how to embed html and css in my fetch data. like for example how can i put a code for table so that the rows of **name** and **city** is properly arrange

[image: Sample output needed to put design]

Comment: check how to send ajax response data first then try...

Comment: i tried to echo a table in my **select.php** it works but when i tried to put an id for example id for a div then use that id for designing css. it doesnt work

Comment: while echoing first total content as string then echo it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try sending the data back wrapped in `pre` tags ~ adding a class too if required perhaps

```
echo '<pre class="dyndata">';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    echo "{$row["name"]}  {$row["city"]}\n";
}
echo '</pre>';
```